# Можно ли использовать имя класса как условие?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп, параметры, аргументы

Прошу прощения за непонятный вопрос, постараюсь пояснить.
К примеру вот небольшой код, который я написал:

```
class Table:
    def __init__(self, width, height, radius):
        self._width = width
        self._height = height
        self._radius = radius


class RTable(Table):
    def calcarea(self):
        return f'Площадь стола равна {self._width * self._height}'


class ETable(Table):
    def calcarea1(self):
        return f'Площадь стола равна {3,14 * (self._radius ** 2)}'
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли как-то сделать, чтобы если экземпляр принадлежал классу `RTable`, то приходилось бы указывать **`2`** аргумента, а если классу `ETable`, то для экземпляра указывался бы только **`1`** аргумент и интерпретатор не ругался на недостаток аргументов?

Я понимаю, что можно задать в каждом дочернем классе свой инициализатор `__init__` и не париться.
Но я бы хотел сделать это как-то похитрее.

Можно ли как-то переопределить конструктор класса `__new__` и указать в нём что-то типа `if` класс такой-то, то бери столько-то аргументов, `elif` класс такой-то , то бери столько-то.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Сделайте параметры конструктора класса `Table` - ключевыми.

```
def __init__(self, width=0, height=0, radius=0):
```

---

```
import math


class Table:
#    def __init__(self, width, height, radius):
    def __init__(self, width=0, height=0, radius=0):   # + width=0, height=0, radius=0
        self._width = width
        self._height = height
        self._radius = radius


class RTable(Table):
    def calcarea(self):
        return f'Площадь стола равна {self._width * self._height}'


class ETable(Table):
    def calcarea1(self):
    
#        return f'Площадь стола равна {3,14 * (self._radius ** 2)}'      # нет 3,14

# так
#        return f'Площадь стола равна {3.14 * (self._radius ** 2)}'       # да  3.14
# или так
        return f'Площадь стола равна {math.pi * (self._radius ** 2)}'     # да  pi
        
        
rTable = RTable(width=10, height=20)        
print(rTable._width, rTable._height, rTable._radius) 
print(rTable.calcarea())

eTable = ETable(radius=12)        
print(eTable._width, eTable._height, eTable._radius) 
print(eTable.calcarea1())
```